# Interfacing of Proximity Sensor with Arduino

Tags: proximity-sensor, arduino-uno

I want to interface OMRON Proximity Sensor E2A-M12KN08-WP-C1 2M with Arduino Uno. How do I interface it with the Arduino? Also, where will I find the relevant starter code? I am new to this and I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see from the [datasheet](https://www.ia.omron.com/data_pdf/cat/e2a_dsheet_d100-e1-01b.pdf?id=1883) this sensor uses a NPN ON/OFF output

[image]

A simple pull-up resistor and a digital input is needed. You need to supply the sensor with a 12 to 24V voltage

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fgdjH3.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

You don't need any starter code, just use the code for [digital read](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/digital-io/digitalread/) , reading LOW  meaning proximity detected.

Comment: Thanks, Dorian. I'll get back to you if I encounter any problem.